# How can I run this android project by using eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, call-graph

I want to compile and run the project (Signal-Android : Openwhisper) by using Eclipse. Is there anyway to do that? (the reason that I have to use Eclipse because of its add-on 'call graph viewer'. I want the call graph of the project. If anyone has other idea, you can post here also)

I have ADT installed already.

when I tried to run it. Lots of error appeared

```
No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar'.

No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.
```

... Actually it has more than 20 lines of error

Errors from Eclipse:

[image: Errors from Eclipse]

I found that most people using Android Studio but I cant find how to create call graph.

I tried to add Appcompat v7 as support Library but in Propertied > android > Library when I click add. It has nothing inside but I'm sure in sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs has v7 appcompat.jar

Comment: The diamond operator can only be used on Java 7+, so you need to change the Build Path or something like that

Comment: right click on your project and goto properties, you will then see red ticks and some errors, then come back and let us know whats up with that. other than that, check your build level, jdk version,errors in your res folders,lib dependencies, clean build.

Comment: I believe the closest thing in Android Studio would be [Call Hierarchy Viewer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/viewing-structure-and-hierarchy-of-the-source-code.html)

Comment: You should really no longer use Eclipse for Android, it's unsupported since quite some time now and projects only work in Eclipse when they are specifically setup to do that. I would print https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf - helps tremendously getting used to AS.

Comment: Google officially stop supporting Eclipse, The open Whisper system android project also migrated to Android studio. clone the open whisper project [here.](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android)

Comment: @cricket_007 I have change to java 1.8. but the the kind of errrors  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light' still exists.
In android studio, call hierarchy in navigate bar cant be clicked. I dont know why.

Comment: Android can't compile Java 1.8 (yet), anyways, you have to update your API versions to v21+ (I think that's the right one)

Comment: @Elltz I dont really know what you mean. In project -> properties, how can I view the red ticks and errors? I show me only settings

Comment: @cricket_007 I have downloaded and installed both API 22 and API 23 via SDK Manager already.

Comment: I believe my last comment addresses how to solve those specific errors.

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry it didn't show up immediately when you replied. I also have android support library (android support reposity) installed. but I'll look deeper in the link you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the android version you have downloaded and installed... and which version is set as target for your application...